# Toggle image in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I now have a player icon that changes to the pause-icon when playing. I'm using this code for changing it:

```
    <script>
      var onImg= "img/play.svg";
      var offImg= "img/pause.svg";
    </script>
```

However it only goes one-way and don't revert back to the play icon when clicked yet again. How can I archive this? I can only find jQuery code, but I want to have a solution thats not dependent on any libraries.

Link to demo: http://mortenhjort.dk/synchub/v2/ (first cover works with audio)

Comment: Can you show us the code that does the actual toggling?

Comment: Even better are you able to knock up a quick and dirty snippet?..

Comment: From that page, he has an inline onclick on the image containing: `this.src = this.src == offImg ? onImg : offImg;` But for the sake of easy answering a snippet would be helpful.

Comment: @DBS `this.src` will return the full URL, I think it should be something like `this.src.indexOf(offImg) != -1 ....`.

Comment: @Titus Indeed it will, I was just clearing up the question. I would suggest you give that as an answer it should solve his problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```js
var on = "http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/04-2013/15-beach-sea-photography.preview.jpg";
var off = "https://s13.postimg.org/lzdaqr6fr/15_beach_sea_photography_preview_Convert_Image.jpg";
var state = false;
var img = document.getElementById("img");

img.onclick = function(){
 if(state){
   img.src = off;
    state = false;
  }
  else{
   img.src = on;
    state = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/04-2013/15-beach-sea-photography.preview.jpg" id="img">
```

The solution is the same when you need to change the **play** icon with a **pause** icon... hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change image ***src*** attribute using pure javascript function as follows

```
img.setAttribute('src',"http://cdn-images.deezer.com/images/cover/fd198aa0a511e33d42c787a364434962/400x400-000000-80-0-0.jpg")
```